# How to view the full exception/error stack trace in Cloudera

Tags: hive, bigdata, cloudera, hue

I am trying to run a query from Cloudera Hue editor for Hive. However the query fails with an exception (which I am trying to explore). How do I see the full stack trace?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the log file location in `/var/log/hive`.

Comment: And for the record I looked and it seems that Thrift does not send back the trace to Hue. Maybe it is better in the latest version.